# Description of determinantal varieties in $\mathbb{P}^n$ that are linear sections of determinantal varieties in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties, hypersurfaces

Fix an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0. Consider an $n$-tuple $(A_1,\ldots, A_n)$ of
$n\times n$ matrices over $k$ and assign to it the determinantal surface in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n-1}$ cut out by the polynomial $\det(x_1A_1+\ldots x_nA_n).$ Now consider a fixed non-zero matrix $G$ of rank $r<n$.

Now let $x$ be the vector with components $x_i$ and $G_{ij}$ be the components of $G$. We may then consider the variety cut out by the polynomial $\det(\sum\limits_{j=1}^nx_jA_iG_{ij}).$ With $y=Gx$, this is then a plane section of the variety cut out by $\det(y_1A_1+\ldots y_nA_n)$ with the $\mathbb{P}_k^{r-1}$ corresponding to the image of $G$, and also a determinantal hypersurface of degree $n$ itself in said $\mathbb{P}_k^{r-1}$.

Now fix a 'generic' $n$-tuple $(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$. 'Generic' means I don't exactly know yet in which sense, but let's say that at least all the matrices are invertible. My question is then whether a generic determinantal hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}_k^{r-1}$ is a linear section of the determinantal hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n-1}$ corresponding to $(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$.  Actually, even knowing whether some fixed determinantal hypersurface has infinitely many nonisomorphic plane sections would be huge for me. This does not seem like a strong statement, but it's non-obvious for me.

Comment: It is well known in the "complexity.  theory circles" that given a polynomial $f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then one can come up with a matrix of linear forms (in variables $x_i$) so that the corresponding matrix has determinant $f$ .. I wonder if won't this imply we can always express a any hypersurface as a determinant hypersurface? perhaps I am not thinking right .. the smallest dimension matrix you need for $f$ is called detrminant complexity of $f$

Comment: Wouldn't a determinantal hypersurface be determined by a tuple of matrices $A_1,\dots, A_r$, and can't you just extend it arbitrarily by additional matrices $A_{r+1},\dots, A_n$, and then set the new variables to $0$, to represent it as a linear section? In fact it seems to me determinantal hypersurfaces are, by definition, linear sections of the determinant hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{n^2-1}$.

Comment: for eaxmple here https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~benleevo/pdf/det-complexity.pdf

Comment: @WillSawin You are absolutely correct, I stated the question poorly. Gonna fix now.

Comment: @skeptic I think (still new to algebraic geometry, may be very wrong) that determinantal varieties in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ are all singular for $n>3$, so not every hypersurface is a determinantal hypersurface.

Comment: @Serge you are absolutely right .. in the "complexity theory" situation, they are working with affine forms .... so in particular in the affine situation we can express any hypersurface as the determinant hypersurface